# caching objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, caching

i have a poltergeist with this code:

javascript code:

```
var cache = {};

cache.init = function()
{   
    if(typeof(this.memory)=='undefined')
        this.memory = {};
};

cache.set = function(key, value)
{
    this.memory[key] = value;
};

cache.get = function(key)
{
    if(console)
    {
        console.log("memory: ");
        console.log(cache.memory);

        console.log("key: "+key);
        console.log(cache.memory[key]);
    }

    if(typeof(cache.memory[key])!='undefined')
        return cache.memory[key];

    return false;
};

var route = {};

route.load = function(url)
{
    var route_list = cache.get('route_list');

    if(route_list==false)
    {
        route_list = this.getList();
        cache.set('route_list', route_list);
    }

    return route_list;
};

route.getList = function()
{
    var result = false;
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'route.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(json)
        {
            result = json;
        }
    });
    return result;
};

cache.init();
route.load();
route.load();
```

i would like to cache some objects in client side with "cache" set and get.

content of route.json file:

```
{    
    "/example":
    {
        "controller":   "example"
    },
    "/example/show":
    {
        "controller":   "example",
        "method":   "show"
    }
}
```

and the result in firebug is:

```
memory:
Object
{
route_list
    Object { /example={...}, /example/show={...}}
}
key: route_list
undefined
```

why is undefined? i can navigate inside the object with firebug o.O

EDIT: i added the second call of route.load(); that i get undefined key

Comment: Show us how you used firebug - I can't see any log statements

Comment: console.log is in cache.get, here the snapshot: http://i.imgur.com/VMSsp.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now I can see your issue. Your code

```
route.load();
route.load();
```

1. tries to get the [uncached] value from the cache:

   1. this logs the memory object
   2. and logs `undefined` because there is nothing
2. because it returned false

   1. get the JSON synchronously
   2. and set it in the cache
3. again tries to get the [cached] value

   1. logs the memory object
   2. and logs the cached object

Everything is executed correctly. Now, you see the memory object two times in your console - but it is the same object, in its current state when inspecting it and not in the state when you logged it. See also

- [How can I change the default behavior of console.log? (*Error console in safari, no add-on*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7389069/1048572)
- [Bug in console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11118758/1048572)
- [Wrong value in console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11214430/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

the error comes from node.js:

```
    socket.emit('zapp_client', '/example');
    socket.emit('zapp_client', '/example/show');
```

i think it does asyncronously:

```
    socket.emit('zapp_client', '/example');
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        socket.emit('zapp_client', '/example/show');
    }, 1000);
```

with this i solved the problem temporarily...