# Why does console.log output modified values even before they have been modified?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome 39 developer tools, this code:

```
var something = [
    {x: 'foo'},
    {x: 'foo'}
];

console.log(something);

something.forEach(function (element) {
    element['x'] = 'baz';
});
```

... outputs:

[image]

Why does `console.log` output modified values even before they have been modified?

A similar **[question from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792368/)** explains that due to a **[chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316)**, `console.log` is "delayed" (does not stringify the input object immediately). But the bug is marked as fixed, so why is this still happening several years later?

Comment: your developer tools also help you if you set a brake point at console.log position and add `watch expression` "something" http://i.stack.imgur.com/xg9rr.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't.

When you output an object with `console.log`, the object is output "by reference"; the values in the console are dynamic, and they will update to reflect the current state of the object.

If you want to output a static string of text about the object, use `console.dir`

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you click on the array of objects, it shows you the updated objects, and not a snapshot of how they looked when you did the console.log.

Think of it as an array of references to the corresponding objects.